# In mule enricher how to acess the MuleMessage

Tags: java, mule

I want to retrive a request context from http request without changing the payload, so I use enricher, but seems the enricher cannot be MuleMessage? I got the following error:

```
org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException: Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "com.ict.cos.transformer.RequestContextBuilder@53dc8cb8" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "com.ict.cos.transformer.RequestContextBuilder" with arguments: "{class org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream}"
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: com.ict.cos.transformer.RequestContextBuilder@53dc8cb8 doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
]
```

My Config:

```
<enricher source="#[message]" target="#[flowVars['requestContext']]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <component doc:name="Build request context">
        <spring-object bean="requestContextBuilder"/>
    </component>
</enricher>
```

The requestContextBuilder:

```
public class RequestContextBuilder {
    public RequestContext build(MuleMessage message) {
        RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext();
        requestContext.setMethod(RESTMethod.get((String) message.getInboundProperty("http.method")));
        requestContext.setAPI((String) message.getInboundProperty("http.request.path"));
        requestContext.setQueryParams((String) message.getInboundProperty("http.query.string"));
        return requestContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: On main page accidentally read this as "How to access the Mule Massage" and I was too curious not to click through...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass in the Message so I would multiple enrichers for each header value you want to be added to the enrichment.

by default the payload will be passed in as the source to the enricher

eg

```
<flow name="orderProcessingFlow">
<inbound-endpoint ref="orderEndpoint"/>
<enricher>
<authorizenet:authorize cardNumber="/order/cc/number" />
<enrich target="#[header:paymentValidated]" source="/authorizenet/authorization/@valid" />
<enrich target="#[header:paymentAuthCode]" source="/authorizenet/authorization/code"/>
</enricher>
<outbound-endpoint ref="orderStep2"/>
</flow>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get the property in header, not put into.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception suggests, try changing your component to make it implement org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable and you will receive a MuleEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Little changes in code will do the needful.

First modify the component class to implement Mule's Callable interface

```
public class RequestContextBuilder implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception { 

        MuleMessage message = eventcontext.getMessage();
        RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext();
        requestContext.setMethod(RESTMethod.get((String) message.getInboundProperty("http.method")));
        requestContext.setAPI((String) message.getInboundProperty("http.request.path"));
        requestContext.setQueryParams((String) message.getInboundProperty("http.query.string"));
        return requestContext;
    }    
}
```

Then modify the enricher to set payload (here it is requestContext)  as the flowVariable.

```
<enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[flowVars['requestContext']]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <component doc:name="Build request context">
        <spring-object bean="requestContextBuilder"/>
    </component>
</enricher>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late response. The RequestConextBuilder do received the message, but if I return my requestContext, the original payload is changed to a string, the request path, why?